# how to apply pinch zoom for particular div tag in html using phonegap?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to just pinch zoom the following content but it not affect the header and footer

```
 <html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
         <div>
           <p align="justfy">Since toolbars can vary in height depending on the content they contain, this option   automatically updates the padding on the page element to ensure that fixed toolbars have adequate space in the document wheenter code heren they are statically positioned, and when scrolled to the top or bottom of the page. When enabled, the padding updates during many operations, such as pageshow, during page transitions, and on resize and orientationchange
         </p></div>
       </body>
    </html>
```